# How do I avoid quads appearing as triangles when twisting a mesh?

Tags: mesh

Is there a trick to avoid that the triangles are visible in the reflection when I do a twist with a deform modifier?

See the file:

[image]

[image: twist]

[image: straight]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

You need to switch to smooth shaded mode with "auto smooth" enabled (auto smooth makes a hard normal on every edge that is greater than the set angle).

[image]

### Method 2

Another method would be to manually mark the edges as sharp, then use an edge split modifier. First select all the "sharp" edges in edit mode, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> --> "Mark Sharp". (Make sure you already clicked <kbd>Smooth</kbd> in object mode)

[image]

Then add an edge split modifier that splits based on sharp edges.

[image]

Note: Hitting <kbd>Smooth</kbd> in object and edit mode do different things (you can smooth certain parts of the mesh in edit mode). For this solution, you will want to hit <kbd>Smooth</kbd> while in object mode.

Comment: Adding smooth shading is the same in both Edit or Object mode; the "Smooth in Object mode" you wrote is *Smooth* option uder *Tools* rollout > *Shading* in the *Toolshelf*. In Edit mode this is `W` > *Shade Smooth*  or in the *Toolshelf* > *Shading/UV* panel > *Shading* rollout.